# Is there a way to set a maximum balance for the assets registered in pallet-assets?

Tags: parachain, xcm, assets

We want to register USDT on our parachain to receive USDT transfered from Statemint, but we need to set a limit to avoid receive too much USDT. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Can you elaborate in what is the use case or  purpose of avoiding to receive "too much" USDT in your parachain?

Answer (score 1):

Limiting the max amount could be tricky, but only the issuer/the account that created the asset could mint it. Therefor limiting how much the issuer print. Hard limits for minting is not enabled by the default asset pallet.
See:
https://docs.rs/pallet-assets/latest/pallet_assets/pallet/struct.Pallet.html#method.mint